# Eloquent relation with father_id and mother_id in same table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I can't imagine the relationships it takes to find the best way the two following tables:

I have a table called "Poeples". It contains "ID, name and sex".

And I have an another table called "Pairs". It contains "ID, name, father_id, mother_id".

A person can belong to several pairs. And a pair can only have one parent_id and mother_id

I don't know if I need to make a foreign key for `mother_id` and `father_id`. I would like `mother_id` to be a poeple and `father_id` also a `poeple` (from the `poeples` table).

Do you have an idea of how?

I plan to use the belongsTo and hasMany relationship, but since there are two foreign keys (I do not know if that's what I have to do), I do not know how to do it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can't make one relation for two fields.

What you need to do is to define two relations in `Pair` model, one would be `PeopleByMother` and another `PeopleByFather` (maybe find better naming).

Therefore a `Pair` model has two `hasOne` relations, and `People` has one `belongsTo` relation that aims for `Pair` model